# NodeJS API makes nested http get request and return response

Tags: node.js, api, http, get, nested

I have a NodeJS API.  The logic in the API needs to make an http get request to google.com, capture the response from google.com, and then return the html response to the original API call.  My problem is capturing the http response from google asynchronously and returning it to the original API call.

```
// Entry point to /api/specialday
module.exports = function(apiReq, apiRes, apiNext) {
  var options = {
    host: 'www.google.com'
  };

  callback = function(googleRes) {
    var str = '';

    // another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
    googleRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
      str += chunk;
    });

    // capture the google response and relay it to the original api call.
    googleRes.on('end', function () {          
      apiRes.send(str);
    });
  }

  http.request(options, callback).end();
}
```

The error I get here is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`.  I understand why I'm getting the error (because apiRes is out of scope), I just can't figure out how to do it right.  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing the above error is because the original response object `apiRes` is gone by the time you have received the response from the google API.

As far as I can tell you will have to `bind()` the `apiRes` twice (untested):

```
callback = function(googleRes) {
  var str = '';

  // another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  googleRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  // capture the google response and relay it to the original api call.
  googleRes.on('end', function () {          
    apiRes.send(str);
  }.bind(apiRes));

}.bind(apiRes)
```

A more modern solution would be to use promises for this task https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

Promises, that's it!  Thanks Michal.  Below is a simplified version of my implementation.

```
// Entry point to /api/specialday
module.exports = function(apiReq, apiRes, apiNext) {

  var p1 = new Promise(
    // The resolver function is called with the ability to resolve or
    // reject the promise
    function(resolve, reject) {

      var options = {
        host: 'www.google.com'
      };

      callback = function(googleRes) {
        var str = '';

        // another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
        googleRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
          str += chunk;
        });

        // capture the google response and relay it to the original api call.
        googleRes.on('end', function () {          
          resolve(str);
        });
      }

      http.request(options, callback).end();
  )};

  p1.then(function(googleHtml) {
    apiRes.status(200).send(googleHtml);
  }
}
```

Then I can run my app and call the api using Postman at `http://localhost:8080/api/gains`:

Answer (score 0):

Directly pipe output with apiRes, sample using request :

```
var request = require("request");

 // Entry point to /api/specialday
 module.exports = function(apiReq, apiRes, apiNext) {
    request.get('http://www.google.fr').pipe(apiRes);
 });
```